# Mat-autocomplete keep recent options when item is selected

Tags: angular, observable, angular-material-7, mat-autocomplete

I am using `mat-autocomplte` with `displayFn` & `async` pipe.

```
this.genericAutoComplete$ = this.acFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(
                startWith(''),
                debounceTime(400),
                distinctUntilChanged(),
                switchMap(value => {
                    if (value && typeof (value) === "string" && value.length > 2) {
                        return this.searchData(value);
                    } else {
                        return of(null);
                    }
                })
            );
```

Now my issue is that when i select option from list `valueChange` will be called & as i am using displayFn value will be object so `else` block will be executed which `returns of(null)`;

What i want to do is display previously **returned/existing list** on focus/click of auto-complete.

So list should not get clear when i select option.

I am not sure how to do that. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you are checking if the value is a `string`, you can check if the value is an `object`. If it is, return to search by the object property that you have defined. Here in my demo, that would be the property `name`:

```ts
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
  startWith(''),
  debounceTime(400),
  switchMap(value => {
    if (value && typeof (value) === "string" && value.length > 2) {
      return this.doFilter(value);
    } 
    // add this check:
    if (typeof (value) === "object") {
      // filter by the object property you have, for me it's "name"
      return this.doFilter(value.name);
    }
    // no need for else, if either of above is truthy, this code wont be executed
    return of(null);
  })
);
```

**[StackBlitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wazyiq-d9d283?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.ts)**